# powershell compare file names and rename

Tags: powershell

I have two directories with files in both of them. File count is different but file names are somewhat equal. For example:

```
C:\dwg 
AR-01-12 - file name0.dwg
AR-01-13 - file name1.dwg
AR-01-14 - file name2.dwg

C:\pdf 
AR-01-11 - file name_.pdf
AR-01-12-R1 - file name0.pdf
AR-01-13 - file name1.pdf
AR-01-14-R5 - file name2.pdf
AR-01-15-R4 - file name3.pdf
```

Using powershell, how to rename files in `C:\dwg` folder so that they have this `R` abbreviation (from Revision) suffix added to name from file names in `C:\pdf` folder ?
The result would be:

```
C:\dwg 
AR-01-12-R1 - file name0.dwg
AR-01-13 - file name1.dwg
AR-01-14-R5 - file name2.dwg
```

My logic would be to check if the first part of the filename is in the pdf directory, if it exists rename file, leaving the extencion.

Comment: Will there be multiple revisions in c:\pdf?

Comment: Only one revision of the same file.

Comment: I posted a rough answer. Let me know if it's suitable, as I'd like to take out some of the fluff.  The community prefers that for the sake of future readers etc...

Comment: Well, you are not showing what you've searched for, tried and what happened when you did. SO rules: [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) --- [Why not upload images of code/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) --- [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: 'My logic would be to check if the first part of the filename is in the pdf directory, if it exists rename file, leaving the extencion.'   ---  We all like helping folks, but one needs to show some effort on their own. You explain, what you'd would do, but never showed what you did. All that being said, I decided to give it a shot for you, as did Steven. Yet, ensure you hit us up next time, remember the rules we all are all supposed to adhere to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I have this correct. To rephrase:

For each file in c:\dwg look for a similarly named pdf file with a revision number in c:\pdf.  If the file is found rename the file in c:\dwg to have the same base name as the PDF file.  Per comments, there may be 1 or zero files matching this criterion in the C:\PDF folder.  Obviously, the rename should only occur if a match is found.

```
$RefFiles = @(Get-ChildItem 'C:\pdf' -File)

Get-ChildItem 'C:\dwg' -File |
ForEach-Object{
    # Calculate a regex to match for in the reference folder.
    $RegEx = $_.BaseName -replace " - ", '-r\d{1,} - '
    $NewName = ($RefFiles.Name -match $RegEx)[0]
    
    If( $NewName ) 
    {
        # Replace extension:
        $NewName = $NewName.SubString( 0, $NewName.LastIndexOf('.') ) + $_.Extension
        Rename-Item $_.FullName $NewName -WhatIf
    }
}
```

Explanation:

1. For each file in C:dwg we calculate a regular expression to match against file names in c:\pdf.
2. Use the -match operator against the array with the previously calculated RegEx. Note: the `Get-ChildItem` command is wrapped in an array subexpression `@(...)`. This is to ensure consistent behavior of the `-match` operator later on. Otherwise, on the off chance only 1 object was returned `-match` would return a Boolean instead of an array of matches...
3. Swap out the extension so we get the new name correct.
4. Then finally execute the `Rename-Item` command.

If there were potential for multiple revisions in the c:\pdf folder, you could add `Sort-Object` & `Select-Object` to say get the latest revision, etc...

Note: The RegEx could be perfected.  Right now it looks for any number of digits after the -r.  If you know the maximum possible revision number you might limit that like `-r\d{1,2}` which would allow 100 possible revision #s from 0 -99.

Comment: Everything works great. Is it possible to modify regex to select files with filenames like `AR-01-12 - file name0 - longer name.dwg` I have tried many regex variants but it just doesn't select files when names contain more than one `' - '`

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from my comment.

Of course, PowerShell allows several ways to do this. Here is a bit different approach. I show the step-thru to show how I came to the result.

```
# Create a file set
'AR-01-12 - file name0.dwg',
'AR-01-13 - file name1.dwg',
'AR-01-14 - file name2.dwg' | 
ForEach {New-Item -Path "d:\temp\dwg\$PSItem" -ItemType File -Force}
Get-ChildItem -Path 'd:\temp\dwg'


'AR-01-11 - file name_.pdf',
'AR-01-12-R1 - file name0.pdf',
'AR-01-13 - file name1.pdf',
'AR-01-14-R5 - file name2.pdf',
'AR-01-15-R4 - file name3.pdf' | 
ForEach {New-Item -Path "d:\temp\pdf\$PSItem" -ItemType File -Force}
Get-ChildItem -Path 'd:\temp\pdf'

# Get only needed files
Clear-Host
(
$DifferenceFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path 'd:\temp\pdf' | 
Where-Object -Property Name -Match '-R\d'
)
# Results
<#
    Directory: D:\temp\pdf

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----         31-Mar-21     13:30              0 AR-01-12-R1 - file name0.pdf
-a----         31-Mar-21     13:30              0 AR-01-14-R5 - file name2.pdf
-a----         31-Mar-21     13:30              0 AR-01-15-R4 - file name3.pdf
#>

($ReferenceFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path 'd:\temp\dwg')
# Results
<#
    Directory: D:\temp\dwg

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----         31-Mar-21     13:30              0 AR-01-12 - file name0.dwg   
-a----         31-Mar-21     13:30              0 AR-01-13 - file name1.dwg   
-a----         31-Mar-21     13:30              0 AR-01-14 - file name2.dwg 
#>


# Validate via string matching
Clear-Host
Get-ChildItem -Path 'd:\temp\pdf' | 
Where-Object -Property Name -Match '-R\d' | 
ForEach{
    ((Get-ChildItem -Path 'd:\temp\dwg').FullName -match ([regex]::Matches($PSItem.BaseName,$BaseNameString))) -replace $BaseNameString, ($PSItem.BaseName -replace '-R.*')
}
# Results
<#
D:\temp\dwg\AR-01-12 - file name0.dwg
D:\temp\dwg\AR-01-14 - file name2.dwg
#>

# Validate rename
Clear-Host
Get-ChildItem -Path 'd:\temp\pdf' | 
Where-Object -Property Name -Match '-R\d' | 
ForEach{
    If (($FilePath = (Get-ChildItem -Path 'd:\temp\dwg').FullName -match ([regex]::Matches($PSItem.BaseName,'..-\d+.-\d+'))))
    {
        $FileUnc = Get-ChildItem -Path $FilePath
        Rename-Item -Path $FileUnc -NewName "$($PSItem.BaseName)$($FileUnc.Extension)" -WhatIf
    }
}
# Results
<#
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: D:\temp\dwg\AR-01-12 - file name0.dwg Destination: D:\temp\dwg\AR-01-12-R1 - file name0.dwg".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: D:\temp\dwg\AR-01-14 - file name2.dwg Destination: D:\temp\dwg\AR-01-14-R5 - file name2.dwg".
#>

# Execute actions
Clear-Host
Get-ChildItem -Path 'd:\temp\pdf' | 
Where-Object -Property Name -Match '-R\d' | 
ForEach{
    If (($FilePath = (Get-ChildItem -Path 'd:\temp\dwg').FullName -match ([regex]::Matches($PSItem.BaseName,'..-\d+.-\d+'))))
    {
        $FileUnc = Get-ChildItem -Path $FilePath
        Rename-Item -Path $FileUnc -NewName "$($PSItem.BaseName)$($FileUnc.Extension)" -Verbose
    }
}
# Results
<#
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: D:\temp\dwg\AR-01-12 - file name0.dwg Destination: D:\temp\dwg\AR-01-12-R1 - file name0.dwg".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: D:\temp\dwg\AR-01-14 - file name2.dwg Destination: D:\temp\dwg\AR-01-14-R5 - file name2.dwg"
#>

# Review results
Get-ChildItem -Path 'd:\temp\dwg'
# Results
<#
    Directory: D:\temp\dwg

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----         31-Mar-21     13:30              0 AR-01-12-R1 - file name0.dwg
-a----         31-Mar-21     13:30              0 AR-01-13 - file name1.dwg
-a----         31-Mar-21     13:30              0 AR-01-14-R5 - file name2.dwg
#>
```

One could have taken the Compare-Object route as well, then work with those results.

```
Clear-Host

$ReferenceFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path 'd:\temp\pdf' | 
                  Where-Object -Property Name -Match '-R\d'

$DifferenceFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path 'd:\temp\dwg'

$CompareObjectSplat = @{
    ReferenceObject  = ($ReferenceFiles -replace '-R.*.*')
    DifferenceObject = ($DifferenceFiles -replace ' - *.*') 
    IncludeEqual     = $true
}
Compare-Object @CompareObjectSplat | 
Where-Object -Property SideIndicator -eq '=='
# Results
<#
AR-01-12    ==           
AR-01-14    == 
#>
```